# Find last record of each day

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I store data about my power consumption, each minute there is a new record, here is an example:

```
{"date":1393156826114,"id":"5309d4cae4b0fbd904cc00e1","adco":"O","hchc":7267599,"hchp":10805900,"hhphc":"g","ptec":"c","iinst":13,"papp":3010,"imax":58,"optarif":"s","isousc":60,"motdetat":"Á"}
```

such that I have around 1440 records a day.

How can I get the last record of each day?

---

Note: I use mongodb in spring java, so I need a query like this:

Example to get all measures  :

```
@Query("{ 'date' : { $gt : ?0 }}")
public List<Mesure> findByDateGreaterThan(Date date, Sort sort);
```

Comment: Have you looked at getting a range representing the date, and then, sorting and limiting to the highest date value?

Answer (score 6):

A bit more modern than the original answer:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$sort": { "date": 1 } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "$subtract": ["$date",{"$mod": ["$date",86400000]}]
    },
    "doc": { "$last": "$$ROOT" }
  }},
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newDocument": "$doc" } }
])
```

The same principle applies that you essentially [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) the collection and then [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) on the required grouping key picking up the [`$last`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) data from the grouping boundary.

Making things a bit clearer since the original writing is that you can use `$$ROOT` instead of specifying every document property, and of course the [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) stage allows you to restore that data fully as the original document form.

But the general solution is still [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) first, then [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) on the common key that is required and keep the [`$last`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) or [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) depending on sort order occurrences from the grouping boundary for the properties that are required.

Also for BSON Dates as opposed to a timestamp value as in the question, see [Group result by 15 minutes time interval in MongoDb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26814496/2313887) for different approaches on how to accumulate for different time intervals actually using and returning BSON Date values.

---

Not quite sure what you are going for here but you could do this in aggregate if my understanding is right. So to get the last record for each day:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Sort in date order  as ascending
    {"$sort": { "date": 1 } },

    // Date math converts to whole day
    {"$project": {
        "adco": 1,
        "hchc": 1,
        "hchp": 1,
        "hhphc": 1,
        "ptec": 1,
        "iinst": 1,
        "papp": 1,
        "imax": 1,
        "optarif": 1,
        "isousc": 1,
        "motdetat": 1,
        "date": 1,
        "wholeDay": {"$subtract": ["$date",{"$mod": ["$date",86400000]}]} 
    }},

    // Group on wholeDay ( _id insertion is monotonic )
    {"$group": 
        "_id": "$wholeDay",
        "docId": {"$last": "$_id" },
        "adco": {"$last": "$adco" },
        "hchc": {"$last": "$hchc" },
        "hchp": {"$last": "$hchp" },
        "hhphc": {"$last": "$hhphc" },
        "ptec": {"$last": "$ptec" },
        "iinst": {"$last": "$iinst" },
        "papp": {"$last": "$papp" },
        "imax": {"$last": "$imax" },
        "optarif": {"$last": "$optarif",
        "isousc": {"$last": "$isouc" },
        "motdetat": {"$last": "$motdetat" },
        "date": {"$last": "$date" },
    }}
])
```

So the principle here is that given the timestamp value, do the date math to project that as the midnight time at the beginning of each day. Then as the `_id` key on the document is already monotonic (always increasing), then simply group on the `wholeDay` value while pulling the `$last` document from the grouping boundary.

If you don't need all the fields then only project and group on the ones you want.

And yes you can do this in the spring data framework. I'm sure there is a wrapped command in there. But otherwise, the incantation to get to the native command goes something like this:

```java
mongoOps.getCollection("yourCollection").aggregate( ... )
```

For the record, if you actually had BSON date types rather than a timestamp as a number, then you can skip the date math:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": { 
            "year": { "$year": "$date" },
            "month": { "$month": "$date" },
            "day": { "$dayOfMonth": "$date" }
        },
        "hchp": { "$last": "$hchp" }
    }}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to format timestamps in the group key as `%Y-%m-%d` (e.g. `2021-12-05`) with [`dateToString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/):

```
// { timestamp: 1638697946000, value: "a" } <= 2021-12-05 9:52:26
// { timestamp: 1638686311000, value: "b" } <= 2021-12-05 6:38:31
// { timestamp: 1638859111000, value: "c" } <= 2021-12-07 6:38:31
db.collection.aggregate([

  { $sort: { timestamp: 1 } },
  // { timestamp: 1638686311000, value: "b" }
  // { timestamp: 1638697946000, value: "a" }
  // { timestamp: 1638859111000, value: "c" }

  { $group: {
    _id: { $dateToString: { date: { $toDate: "$timestamp" }, format: "%Y-%m-%d" } },
    last: { $last: "$$ROOT" }
  }},
  // { _id: "2021-12-07", last: { timestamp: 1638859111000, value: "c" } }
  // { _id: "2021-12-05", last: { timestamp: 1638697946000, value: "a" } }

  { $replaceWith: "$last" }
])
// { timestamp: 1638697946000, value: "a" } <= 2021-12-05 9:52:26
// { timestamp: 1638859111000, value: "c" } <= 2021-12-07 6:38:31
```

This:

- first `$sort`s documents by chronological order of `timestamp`s such that we can latter on pick newest documents based on their order.
- then `$group`s documents by their `%Y-%m-%d`-formatted timestamps:

  - by first converting the timestamp into a datetime: `{ $toDate: "$timestamp" }`
  - and then converting the associated datetime into a string only representing the year, month and day: `{ $dateToString: { date: ..., format: "%Y-%m-%d" } }`
  - such that for each group (i.e. date), we can pick the `$last` (i.e. newest since chronologically sorted) matching document

    - and the pick is the whole document as represented by [`$$ROOT`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#mongodb-variable-variable.ROOT)
- finally cleans up the group result with a [`$replaceWith`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceWith/) stage (alias for `$replaceRoot`).