# Group result by 15 minutes time interval in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a "status" collection like this strcture -

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("545a0b63b03dbcd1238b4567"),
    status: 1004,
    comment: "Rem dolor ipsam placeat omnis non. Aspernatur nobis qui nisi similique.",
    created_at: ISODate("2014-11-05T11:34:59.804Z")
},
{
    _id: ObjectId("545a0b66b03dbcd1238b4568"),
    status: 1001,
    comment: "Sint et eos vero ipsa voluptatem harum. Hic unde voluptatibus et blanditiis quod modi.",
    created_at: ISODate("2014-11-05T11:35:02.814Z")
}
....
....
```

**I need to get result grouped by 15 minutes interval from that collection.**

Comment: Is their something in the provided answer that is unclear or does not apply to your situation? Noting that it is still not accepted.

Comment: Don't bother, he already took answer, why bother yourself with accepting answers.

Answer (score 172):

There are a couple of ways to do this.

The first is with [Date Aggregation Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/), which allow you to dissect the "date" values in documents. Specifically for "grouping" as the primary intent:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "year": { "$year": "$created_at" },
      "dayOfYear": { "$dayOfYear": "$created_at" },
      "hour": { "$hour": "$created_at" },
      "interval": {
        "$subtract": [ 
          { "$minute": "$created_at" },
          { "$mod": [{ "$minute": "$created_at"}, 15] }
        ]
      }
    }},
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }}
])
```

The second way is by using a little trick of when a date object is subtracted (or other direct math operation) from another date object, then the result is a numeric value representing the epoch timestamp milliseconds between the two objects. So just using the epoch date you get the epoch milliseconds representation. Then use date math for the interval:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "$subtract": [
                { "$subtract": [ "$created_at", new Date("1970-01-01") ] },
                { "$mod": [ 
                    { "$subtract": [ "$created_at", new Date("1970-01-01") ] },
                    1000 * 60 * 15
                ]}
            ]
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

So it depends on what kind of output format you want for the grouping interval. Both basically represent the same thing and have sufficient data to re-construct as a "date" object in your code.

You can put anything else you want in the "grouping operator" portion after the grouping `_id`. I'm just using the basic "count" example in lieu of any real statement from yourself as to what you really want to do.

---

#### MongoDB 4.x and Upwards

There were some additions to Date Aggregation Operators since the original writing, but from MongoDB 4.0 there will be actual "real casting of types" as opposed to the basic math tricks done here with BSON Date conversion.

For instance we can use [`$toLong`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/toLong/) and [`$toDate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/) as new helpers here:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "$toDate": {
        "$subtract": [
          { "$toLong": "$created_at" },
          { "$mod": [ { "$toLong": "$created_at" }, 1000 * 60 * 15 ] }
        ]
      }
    },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }}
])
```

That's a bit shorter and does not require defining an external BSON Date for the "epoch" value as a constant in defining the pipeline so it's pretty consistent for all language implementations.

Those are just two of the "helper" methods for type conversion which all tie back to the [`$convert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/) method, which is a "longer" form of the implementation allowing for custom handling on `null` or error in conversion.

It's even possible with such casting to get the `Date` information from the `ObjectId` of the primary key, as this would be a reliable source of "creation" date:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "$toDate": {
        "$subtract": [
          { "$toLong": { "$toDate": "$_id" }  },
          { "$mod": [ { "$toLong": { "$toDate": "$_id" } }, 1000 * 60 * 15 ] }
        ]
      }
    },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }}
])
```

So "casting types" with this sort of conversion can be pretty powerful tool.

> **Warning** - `ObjectId` values are limited to precision to the **second** only for the internal time value that makes up part of their data allowing the [`$toDate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/) conversion. The actual inserted "time" is most probably dependent on the driver in use. Where *precision* is required, it's still recommended to use a discrete BSON Date field instead of relying on `ObjectId` values.

Comment: too bad i can't accept for him - really useful answer !

Comment: i couldn't agree more @Petrov

Comment: Thanks for providing these good solutions! I think there might be a small error in your first example. You are missing the grouping by hour (in order to retrieve the 15 minutes intereval – which I assume – should be by the hour). So you would need to add `"hour": { "$hour": "$created_at" },` after the `dayOfYear`-line

Comment: Mongodb **4.0** has released in **2018** and you know these aggregations from **2014**... How ???

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet, he edited his answer on 26 Apr 2018.

Comment: Could anyone please help on related question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61131299/mongodb-datetostring-format-to-show-time-by-15min-interval

Answer (score 17):

I like the other answer here, and mostly for the use of date math instead of aggregation date operators which while helpful can also be a little obscure.

The only thing I want to add here is that you can also return a `Date` object from the aggregation framework by this approach as opposed to the "numeric" timestamp as the result. It's just a little extra math on the same principles, using [**`$add`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/add/):

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "$add": [
                { "$subtract": [
                    { "$subtract": [ "$current_date", new Date(0) ] },
                    { "$mod": [ 
                        { "$subtract": [ "$current_date", new Date(0) ] },
                        1000 * 60 * 15
                    ]}
                ] },
                new Date(0)
            ]
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

The `Date(0)` contructs in JavaScript here represent the same "epoch" date in a shorter form, as 0 millisecond from epoch is epoch. But the main point is that when the "addition" to another BSON date object is done with a numeric identifier, then the inverse of the described condition is true and the end result is actually now a `Date`.

All drivers will return the native `Date` type to their language by this approach.

Answer (score 9):

Another useful way:

```javascript
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$group: {
    _id: { 
      overallTime: { 
        $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%dT%H", date: "$created_at" } 
      },
      interval: { $trunc: { $divide: [{ $minute: "$created_at" }, 15 ]}}
    },
  }},
])
```

And more easier for *min*, *hour*, *day* intervals:

```javascript
var format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M"; // 1 min
var format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H"; // 1 hour
var format = "%Y-%m-%d"; // 1 day

db.collection.aggregate([
  {$group: {
    _id: { $dateToString: { format: format, date: "$created_at" } },
  }},
])
```

Answer (score 7):

A little more beautiful for mongo db.version() < 3.0

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$match: {created_at:{$exists:1}}},
    {$group: {
        _id: {$add:[
            {$dayOfYear: "$created_at" },
            {$multiply: [{$year: "$created_at"}, 1000]}
        ]},
        count: {$sum: 1 }
    }},
    {$sort:{_id:-1}}
])
```

Answer (score 6):

### MongoDB 5.x and Upwards

date truncation is now supported in aggergation pipelines, example:

```
{
  $group: {
   "_id": { "$dateTrunc": { date: "$created_at", unit: "minute", binSize: 15 } },
   "count" : { $sum: 1 }
  }
},
```

You can also find useful info about window functions and dateTrunc [here](https://www.mongodb.com/features/mongodb-time-series-data)

Comment: Or `{ $count: {} }` instead of `{ $sum: 1 }`

Answer (score 2):

@Neil Lunn's answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/26814496/8474325 for MongoDb 4.x upwards is fantastic. But there is a small mistake in the code where he uses ObjectId for the aggregation. The Line `{ "$toDate": "_id" }` has to be changed to `{ "$toDate": "$_id" }` for the code to work.

Here's the corrected code.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
      "_id": {
          "$toDate": {
              "$subtract": [
                  { "$toLong": { "$toDate": "$_id" }  },
                  { "$mod": [ { "$toLong": { "$toDate": "$_id" } }, 1000 * 60 * 15 ] }
              ]
          }
      },
      "count": { "$sum": 1 }
   }}
])
```

Answer (score 1):

With MongoDB v5.0+, you can use [`$setWindowFields`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setWindowFields/#std-label-setWindowFields-time-range-window-examples) to perform computation on nearby documents(i.e. documents within 15 minute interval). In following example, it will count all documents which is 15 minutes before or after the current document. You can adjust it by changing the `window` param.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $setWindowFields: {
      partitionBy: null,
      sortBy: {
        created_at: 1
      },
      output: {
        count: {
          $count: {},
          window: {
            range: [
              -15,
              15
            ],
            unit: "minute"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Jv8IMgFjoWH) for your reference.

Comment: A range of -15 to +15 gives a 30 Minute interval - not 15 Minutes.