# mongodb: old data aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a script that collects data from somewhere and writes it into a mongodb collection every 10 minutes. Then we have a frontend that displays the historical trends of data in form of graphs/charts etc. I noticed that now we have data for around 2 years. All the data is at a 10 minute resolution. Generally, we like to see data at resolution of 10 minutes for past 6 months only. 6 month to 1 year old data is checked at an hourly resolution while older than an year at a daily resolution.

This means that we should somehow aggregate the 10 minute resolution data to higher resolution if its older than some time. E.g. average out (or may be max/min depending on the parameter) the data older than a year at an hourly basis and remove the 10 entries and make a new single entry.

Are there any frameworks available out there that could support such policy based data management?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Group result by 15 minutes time interval in MongoDb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26814427/group-result-by-15-minutes-time-interval-in-mongodb)

Comment: Please show us some example data!