# MongoDb count of elements with grouping by timespan

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I don't understand how to implement the following query via MongoDb :

I need to take a count of documents but with condition that only one document will be taken for each time span which equals 30 minutes. I.e. if in 60 minutes time span i have two documents then i need to add only one in total count. Each document will contain `created` field that contains mentioned date. 
I have `MongoDb v. 3.0.2` and `c# MongoDb driver v. 2.0` but will be enough if you give me an advice how to implement it via native `MongoDb` query.

Comment: Also added [my own take](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32137234/5031275) there on the duplicate on returning as valid BSON `Date` type for translation in any language impelementation as a result.