# Optimal query for Mongodb to get single latest record from multiple time intervals using single query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have collection which stores data with time stamp. I want to get in way such as get every single record from collection from date x to y at interval of z minutes. Then how can i do it in single query?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a aggregation with which you group your date on a time interval. See this similar question with answers here the data is grouped on a 15min interval: [Group result by 15 minutes time interval in MongoDb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26814427/group-result-by-15-minutes-time-interval-in-mongodb)