# Query datetime by time of day in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, datetime, mongodb-query

I have a collection of objects in my mongoDB containing datetimes among other values.
How would I go about querying the objects by datetime, where the timestamp is set to be at 9 o'clock?

So if I have the following collection...

```
id : 1, date : ISODate("2017-07-16T09:00:00.000+0000")
id : 2, date : ISODate("2017-01-17T07:00:00.000+0000")
id : 3, date : ISODate("2017-07-27T09:00:00.000+0000")
id : 4, date : ISODate("2017-03-20T09:00:00.000+0000")
id : 5, date : ISODate("2017-03-07T10:00:00.000+0000")
id : 6, date : ISODate("2017-07-04T11:00:00.000+0000")
```

The return value should be...

```
id : 1, date : ISODate("2017-07-16T09:00:00.000+0000")
id : 3, date : ISODate("2017-07-27T09:00:00.000+0000")
id : 4, date : ISODate("2017-03-20T09:00:00.000+0000")
```

I'm fairly new to MongoDB and not very experienced with Js so please try and keep it as simple as you can. To that note Neil Lunn marked this question as a duplicate of 
[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26814427/group-result-by-15-minutes-time-interval-in-mongodb), which I feel is partially correct, but it's also more complex than I need.

I don't need grouping or anything of that nature, I just want a query that tells me which documents exist containing this timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an aggregate pipeline to convert [the date to its timepart](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) and then match on that converted value. For example:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            timePart: {$dateToString: { format: "%H:%M:%S:%L", date: "$date"}},     
            date: 1

        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            timePart: '09:00:00:000'
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            date: 1
        }
    }
])
```

You can think of this as a pipeline; the output from the first `$project` step becomes the input to the `$match` step. The `$project` step outputs - for every document in the underlying collection - a document containing the `_id`, the `date` and a new attribute named `timePart` which has been populated with the time part from the date attribute. The `$match` step then matches these documents against your filter criteria (in your example this is `09:00:00:000` i.e. 9am) and then the documents which are matched are then forwarded to the next step which uses the `$project` operator again to discard the timePart attribute since, I assume, that is only relevant for saerching and should not be included in the end result.

Breaking it down, the output of the first step looks like this:

```
{
   "_id" : 1,
   date : ISODate("2017-07-16T09:00:00.000+0000"),
   timePart: "09:00:00.000"
},
{
   "_id" : 2,
   date : ISODate("2017-01-17T07:00:00.000+0000"),
   timePart: "07:00:00.000"
},
...
```

The second step excludes the document with `id: 2` because its timePart does not match `09:00:00.000` and then forwards the document with `id: 1` to the third stage which then selects - from those documents forwarded by step 2 - the fields `_id` and `date` thereby giving you:

```
{
   "_id" : 1,
   date : ISODate("2017-07-16T09:00:00.000+0000")
},
{
   "_id" : 3,
   date : ISODate("2017-07-27T09:00:00.000+0000")
},
{
   "_id" : 4,
   date : ISODate("2017-03-20T09:00:00.000+0000")
}
```

Note: this approach must transform the date attribute of **every** document before applying the match stage, if that's worryingly inefficient for you then you might want to reconsider how you are persisting this data.

Comment: I'm fairly new to MongoDB, so let me just sum this up to see if I get this correctly: for each document you take the date, format it, turn it into a string, then into a timepart, and then you match it against another timepart made from a string?

Comment: I've updated the answer to explain the nature of an aggregation pipeline. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, this worked like a charm and you helped me understand this all a little better.

Comment: You're welcome ...