# Mongodb time series data aggregation

Tags: mongodb, time-series

He guys,

I have a following time series mongodb data. This is one day of some measurements. I need to aggregate this data by some interval (e.g. 15 minutes) for the last x hours. Could you help me?

```
{
  timestamp_hour: ISODate("2013-10-10T23:00:00.000Z"),
  type: “spot_EURUSD”,
  values: {
    0: { 0: 1.2343, 1: 1.2343, …, 59: 1.2343},
    1: { 0: 1.2343, 1: 1.2343, …, 59: 1.2343},
    …,
    22: { 0: 1.2343, 1: 1.2343, …, 59: 1.2343},
    23: { 0: 1.2343, 1: 1.2343, …, 59: 1.2343}
  }
}
```

Comment: What is a document you want to get as a result? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MongoDB Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) for aggregate data and for this task you can use[MongoDB Aggregation date](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/).

Here is a similar problem [Group result by 15 minutes time interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26814427/group-result-by-15-minutes-time-interval-in-mongodb)