# Accessing a portion of a datetimeoffset in a mongodb linq query

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

Is it possible in mongo db to write a query to access the year portion of a DateTimeOffset

i.e.

```
var result = from x in coll.AsQueryable()
             where x.MyDate.Year == 2018
             select x;
```

Can I do this with a custom serializer ? if so how ? and how does Linq handle it? or would I have to cut the query in raw Json ?

Comment: Where MyDate >= 1st Jan 2018 and MyDate < 1st Jan 2019.

Comment: As noted, it's a "date range". Also various examples at [MongoDB .NET Driver Group By Time Range](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50552288/2313887) if the other existing examples are not clear enough.

Comment: Tim. They are all duplicates. You cannot "select by **year**" there is only *"date ranges"* just like the existing answers and the good first commenter also said. Read them and learn how it's done.

Comment: @NeilLunn actually its only your link in the comment that i'd agree is a duplicate those other 2 not so much - and thanks, its actually your answer (in that link) that helps ;-)

Comment: @mjwills yes that will work I think - I was not wanting to use a range (mainly for readability) but if I have to I have to

Comment: Let's agree to disagree on that since I think they all say the same thing about the point that matters here. BTW if you find a useful post then there's supposed to be an action for that here.

Comment: @NeilLunn - Turns out I had upvoted that a couple weeks ago, when looking for some other issue - If I could upvote twice I would :-)