# How to get the difference in millis between a field value and current time in Mongo collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection where a single document looks like this:

```
{
  "_id" : "123456789",
   "created_timestamp" : "1522950461031"
}
```

As you can see, the created_timestamp date is stored as the epoch value as a String. (unfortunately can't change that now)

I need to write a query that will calculate the "time elapsed" i.e, `current time - created_time` for all of the documents at any given point in time.

This is what I tried so far:

```
db.getCollection('testEntity').aggregate([
{$match : {"_id" : "123456789"}},
{$project: {_id : 1, created_timestamp: 1 ,
    dateDifference: { $subtract: [ new Date() , new  Date("$created_timestamp")]}}}])
```

But it does not compute the difference correctly. I think the field is not getting detected correctly within the `$subtract`. Any suggestions to rewrite it correctly?

Comment: `dateDifference: { $subtract: [ new Date() , "$created_timestamp" ] }` will subtract the two BSON dates and return the milliseconds time difference between them. There's even further demonstration on going back to BSON Date of getting milliseconds since epoch on [Group Result by 15 minute Time Interval](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26814496/2313887). But your field here is a "string" and not numeric. Right now MongoDB cannot do that, and there is information on that there as well.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into converting my field to numeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDb doesn't provides type changes. And in your case timestamp should be in number for your conditions to be applied. So, i suggest that you explicitly convert the data in your db by some programming code using update query.