# Mongoose Query for get data by specify interval

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have mongodb collection with below document:

```
{

    "_id" : ObjectId("5ba605ebf57bd40fb4900f76"),
    "__v" : 0.0,
    "Timestamp" : 20180823095157.0,
    "Speed" : 3.0,
    "Altitude" : 0.0,
    "Latitude" : 23.19364,
    "Longitude" : 72.638502,
    "battery" : 90.0,
    "VehicleId" : "ISG503"
}

{

    "_id" : ObjectId("5ba605ebf57bd40fb4900f77"),
    "__v" : 0.0,
    "Timestamp" : 20180823095158.0,
    "Speed" : 3.0,
    "Altitude" : 0.0,
    "Latitude" : 23.193662,
    "Longitude" : 72.63849,
    "battery" : 89.0,
    "VehicleId" : "ISG503"
}

{

    "_id" : ObjectId("5ba605ebf57bd40fb4900f78"),
    "__v" : 0.0,
    "Timestamp" : 20180823095159.0,
    "Speed" : 3.0,
    "Altitude" : 0.0,
    "Latitude" : 23.193668,
    "Longitude" : 72.638493,
    "battery" : 90.0,
    "VehicleId" : "ISG503"
}
```

here the timestamp is YYYYMMDDhhmmss format.

I have every seconds data but I want to get data with every 15 sec interval only in mongoose query.

Comment: have you tried this way? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26814427/group-result-by-15-minutes-time-interval-in-mongodb

Comment: yes @ShivamPandey i have already tried this but as Timestamp is not in ISODate formate this will not working.