# Group overlap series by 15 minutes time interval in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a "event" collection like this structure -

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("545a0b63b03dbcd1238b4567"),
    status: 1004,
    created_at: ISODate("2014-11-05T11:34:59.804Z"),
    closed_at: ISODate("2014-11-05T11:34:59.804Z")
},
{
    _id: ObjectId("545a0b66b03dbcd1238b4568"),
    status: 1001,
    created_at: ISODate("2014-11-05T11:35:02.814Z"),
    closed_at: ISODate("2014-11-05T11:34:59.804Z")
}
....
```

I need to get result grouped by 15 minutes overlap interval from that collection. I found a similar solution, but the duration is not used here. [group by start without duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26814427/group-result-by-15-minutes-time-interval-in-mongodb#)

added a picture for explanation [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbL6U.png)

Comment: What do you mean duration is not used. Did you try that. See the `_id` expressions in that answer.

Comment: I need count overlap from created_at to closed_at by some interval. In answer used only create_at, without duration

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet , I added a picture for explanation of what needs to be calculated.