# MongoDB Aggregation framework and windowing operations over time series data

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm unable to find an information about windowing operations over time series data in MongoDB Aggregation framework.

Does it support windowing operations over time series data? For example, I need to count some aggregated values based on the document timestamp each 5 minute windows and store such aggregations in separate documents for feature usage. Is it possible with MongoDB Aggregation framework to achieve this with help of MongoDB Aggregation framework pipeline and stages?

Comment: There is some related information as a feature request (MongoDB jira): [aggregation: support windowing operation on pipelines](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4437).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to group them in 5min windows and then run the aggregation:

```
db.users.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "$toDate": {
        "$subtract": [
          { "$toLong": "$signedUp" },
          { "$mod": [ { "$toLong": "$signedUp" }, 1000 * 60 * 5 ] }
        ]
      }
    },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }}
])
```

The above example counts how many users signed up every 5 mins.

Example taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26814496/125740).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Please correct me if I'm wrong, but looks like such kind of solution will work in real-time during the query execution time and not during the document insert time? If so, how about the performance of this solution on big amount of documents in each window?

Comment: So, in other words - I'm interested in aggregations on `INSERT/UPDATE` and not on `SELECT`

Comment: This is real time. But you can improve this in a couple of ways; support the query with index, run it at defined intervals and output using `$merge` to a different collection, attach change streams on raw collection and pre-aggregate on every insert/update

Comment: Thanks. When you are talking about `change streams on raw collection and pre-aggregate`  - you are talking about solution based on MongoDB functionalty or I shoul use 3rdparty tools/frameworks in order to do this job outside of MongoDB?

Comment: Change Streams are supported by MongoDB natively, but written in app scope i.e. you write the code (for the subscriber). So, not 3rd party, but outside database server.