# How to get average of one field value per min from mongo with aggregate query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I saved my data in MongoDb as

```
{
  "_id": "ObjectId(\"5fec31b6b9022035abbbf7cc\")",
  "message": {
    "date": "2020-12-30 13:20:26",
    "time": "2020-12-30T07:50:26.000Z",
    "ID": "005",
    "P": 1.36
  }
},
{
  "_id": "ObjectId(\"5fec31b5b9022035abbbf7c2\")",
  "message": {
    "date": "2020-12-30 13:20:24",
    "time": "2020-12-30T07:50:24.000Z",
    "ID": "005",
    "P": 1.5
  }
 
},
{
  "_id": "ObjectId(\"5fec31b0b9022035abbbf7b3\")",
  "message": {
    "date": "2020-12-30 13:20:19",
    "time": "2020-12-30T07:50:19.000Z",
    "ID": "005",
    "P": 1.63
  }
  
}
```

I want to find the average of P value per min.
I've tried [Group result by 15 minutes time interval in MongoDb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26814427/group-result-by-15-minutes-time-interval-in-mongodb)
but I got an error in the time field.

```
db.pressure.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "year": { "$year": "message.time" },
      "dayOfYear": { "$dayOfYear": "message.time" },
      "hour": { "$hour": "message.time" },
      "interval": {
        "$subtract": [ 
          { "$minute": "message.time" },
          { "$mod": [{ "$minute": "message.time"}, 1] }
        ]
      }
    },
      
  
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }
  }
  
])
```

{
"message" : "can't convert from BSON type string to Date",
"ok" : 0,
"code" : 16006,
"codeName" : "Location16006",
"name" : "MongoError"
}

Comment: Storing date/time values as **string** is a design flaw. Use always proper `Date` object - then your aggregation pipeline will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few Fixes:

- You need to convert your string date to date type using `$toDate` **(From MongoDB 4.0)**, `$addFields` will update `message.time` field to date type
- `$year, $hour` etc operators requires reference of field using $ sign you missed it in `message.time`
- use `$avg` to get average of `message.P`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $addFields: { "message.time": { $toDate: "$message.time" } } },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "year": { "$year": "$message.time" },
        "dayOfYear": { "$dayOfYear": "$message.time" },
        "hour": { "$hour": "$message.time" },
        "interval": {
          "$subtract": [
            { "$minute": "$message.time" },
            { "$mod": [{ "$minute": "$message.time" }, 15] }
          ]
        }
      },
      "count": { "$count": 1 },
      "average": { "$avg": "$message.P" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5jrkoc_e_KK)

---

**MongoDB 3.6:** you can use [$dateFromString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/index.html)

```
  {
    $addFields: {
      "message.time": {
        $dateFromString: { dateString: "$message.time" }
      }
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZdO_0Pa80L-)

Comment: "time": "2020-12-30T07:50:24.000Z", is this type string .but in mongo it showing as date type

Comment: {
 "message" : "Unrecognized expression '$toDate'",
 "ok" : 0,
 "code" : 168,
 "codeName" : "InvalidPipelineOperator",
 "name" : "MongoError"
}

Comment: what is the version of your mongodb?

Comment: i think its 3.6

Comment: `$toDate` is from mongodb v4.0 i have added another option for 3.6 it is `$dateFromString`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226603/discussion-between-akhilav-and-turivishal).