# MongoDB (via python): aggregate data every 30 minutes

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, pymongo

I was using the following query to aggregate (and average) some data at each hour:

[Demo on MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kyzVHSJG4Op)

ad I successfully managed to do so.

I now want to aggregate every 30 minutes. I am trying to change the aformentioned query but I feel that is not possible. I already tried with the asnwers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26814427/group-result-by-15-minutes-time-interval-in-mongodb) but I am getting some weird `pymongo.errors.OperationFailure` type of errors

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group result by 15 minutes time interval in MongoDb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26814427/group-result-by-15-minutes-time-interval-in-mongodb)

Comment: This is exactly the question I linked in the question

Comment: Oh sorry - didn't see that. If you post your full code and stack trace that might help.