# How to get last document of each day in MongoDB collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a model `Entry` to which includes details of a hospital at a particular time. The data looks like this:

```js
{
  "_id": "5ef9c7337874820008c1a026",
  "date": 1593427763640,
  //... some data
  "hospital": {
    "_id": "5ef8d06630c364000840bb6d",
    "name": "City Hospital",
    //... some data
  },
}
```

I want to get the last query of each day grouped by the hospital ID. In MySQL, it can be achieved using INNER JOIN. How can I do it using MongoDB?

Comment: You can find some related information at: [SQL to Aggregation Mapping Chart](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

Given a day, calculate start and end of a day.
This is to be used for filtering records, `$match`

```
start_of_day_ephocs=
end_of_day_ephocs=
```

Aggregate Query

sort by date, Group by hospital id,and select first document

```
db.Entry.aggregate(
   [
    { "$match": { "date": {"$gte":start_of_day_ephocs,"$lte":end_of_day_ephocs }} },
    { "$sort": { "date": -1 } },
     {
       $group:
         {
           "_id": "$hospital._id",
           "last_document": { "$first": "$$ROOT" }
         }
     }
   ]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider a sales collection with the following documents:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "abc", "date" : ISODate("2014-01-01T08:00:00Z"), "price" : 10, "quantity" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 2, "item" : "jkl", "date" : ISODate("2014-02-03T09:00:00Z"), "price" : 20, "quantity" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 3, "item" : "xyz", "date" : ISODate("2014-02-03T09:05:00Z"), "price" : 5, "quantity" : 5 }
{ "_id" : 4, "item" : "abc", "date" : ISODate("2014-02-15T08:00:00Z"), "price" : 10, "quantity" : 10 }
{ "_id" : 5, "item" : "xyz", "date" : ISODate("2014-02-15T09:05:00Z"), "price" : 5, "quantity" : 10 }
{ "_id" : 6, "item" : "xyz", "date" : ISODate("2014-02-15T12:05:10Z"), "price" : 5, "quantity" : 5 }
{ "_id" : 7, "item" : "xyz", "date" : ISODate("2014-02-15T14:12:12Z"), "price" : 5, "quantity" : 10 }
```

The following operation first sorts the documents by item and date, and then in the following $group stage, groups the now sorted documents by the item field and uses the $last accumulator to compute the last sales date for each item:

```
db.sales.aggregate(
   [
     { $sort: { item: 1, date: 1 } },
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id: "$item",
           lastSalesDate: { $last: "$date" }
         }
     }
   ]
)
```

The operation returns the following results:

```
{ "_id" : "xyz", "lastSalesDate" : ISODate("2014-02-15T14:12:12Z") }
{ "_id" : "jkl", "lastSalesDate" : ISODate("2014-02-03T09:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : "abc", "lastSalesDate" : ISODate("2014-02-15T08:00:00Z") }
```

[Resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22202938/find-last-record-of-each-day)

Comment: This does help me, but I only get the last entry, but not of each day. I want to get the weekly results.