# How to find last record of each day in mongodb using given timestamps?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using MongoDB to store data, every 15 mins once one new record will be inserted into DB.So I want to download the report using the given timestamps.
If I select the Friday, January 1, 2021 12:00:00 AM(**1609459200000**) timestamp to Sunday, January 3, 2021 11:59:59 PM(**1609718399000**) timestamp I should get only 3 records as a response.

> db.vehicle.aggregate(    [
> { "$match": { "time": {"$gte":1609459200000,"$lte":1609718399000 }} },
> { "$sort": { "time": 1 } },
> {
> $group:
> {
> _id: "$speed",
> time: { $last: "$time" }
> }
> }    ] );

```
I tried the above query but it's giving all the records
```

Thank you.

**Example DB Record:**

```
// Day 1
{
   "_id":"100",
   "vehical":"train_1",
   "speed":"100kmh",
   "time":1609459200000,
   "starting_point":12
},
{
   "_id":"101",
   "vehical":"train_1",
   "speed":"120kmh",
   "time":1609460100000,
   "starting_point":13
},
{
   "_id":"102",
   "vehical":"train_1",
   "speed":"125kmh",
   "time":1609461000000,
   "starting_point":14
},
// Day 2
{
   "_id":"201",
   "vehical":"train_1",
   "speed":"100kmh",
   "time":1609545600000,
   "starting_point":15
},
{
   "_id":"202",
   "vehical":"train_1",
   "speed":"130kmh",
   "time":1609546500000,
   "starting_point":16
},
// Day 3
{
   "_id":"301",
   "vehical":"train_1",
   "speed":"100kmh",
   "time":1609632000000,
   "starting_point":20
},
{
   "_id":"302",
   "vehical":"train_1",
   "speed":"140kmh",
   "time":1609632900000,
   "starting_point":21
}
```

**Response:**

```
// Day 1
{
   "_id":"102",
   "vehical":"train_1",
   "speed":"125kmh",
   "time":1609461000000,
   "starting_point":14
},
// Day 2
{
   "_id":"202",
   "vehical":"train_1",
   "speed":"130kmh",
   "time":1609546500000,
   "starting_point":16
},
// Day 3
{
   "_id":"302",
   "vehical":"train_1",
   "speed":"140kmh",
   "time":1609632900000,
   "starting_point":21
}
```

Comment: Why do you store date/time values as number? Use proper `Date` objects.

Comment: IoT devices will give date/time data as a timestamp so data is storing as a number, I posted here a sample data object

Comment: Maybe enclose the timestamp value by `new Date(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
db.vehicle.aggregate([
   { $match: { time: { $gte: 1609459200000, $lte: 1609718399000 } } },
   { $set: { timestamp: { $toDate: "$time" } } },
   { $sort: { time: 1 } },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: {
            $dateFromParts: {
               year: { $year: "$timestamp" },
               month: { $month: "$timestamp" },
               day: { $dayOfMonth: "$timestamp" }
            }
         },
         last: { $last: "$$ROOT" }
      }
   },
   { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$last" } }
]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Someone else posted a similar question 7 months ago. This might answer your question: [How to get last document of each day in MongoDB collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62636793/how-to-get-last-document-of-each-day-in-mongodb-collection)

If that doesn't work for you and  you know that the last record of the day will always be generated at the same time, you should be able to build a query with $hour and $minute.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/hour/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/minute/

Comment: Did you try using $hour and $minute, the accepted answer in the other StackOverflow question, or both?  
It would be helpful if you included the queries you were using in your question (at least the relevant parts).